# Why does Kurtz allow Willard to walk around free?

Tags: plot-explanation, apocalypse-now

During the ending of *Apocalypse Now* Kurtz knows that Willard is there to kill him. Why does he let him walk around free?

Comment: Apart from being somewhat insane?

Comment: Short answer: the film places more emphasis on freewill and fate than the novel does (in the novel, Kurtz is consumed by the jungle--the Id--dying of his 'sickness'). In the film, Kurtz is leaving the judgement of his actions to Willard (i.e. Kurtz is avoiding answering the inevitable judgement of his own actions). If Willard kills Kurtz as an act of fate, Kurtz's atrocities are sanctified by a higher power. If Willard kills him out of his own freewill, Kurtz's atrocities are simply an inevitable aspect of the human condition. Either way, Kurtz avoids taking responsibility.

Comment: @wcullen That looks like a great answer, put it on the answer field!